# Numpy delete column out of 3d Array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have an 3d Numpy Array e.g.:

```
array = np.array([[[1,2],[3,4]],[[0,5],[6,7]]])
=[[[1 2]
   [3 4]]
  [[0 5]
   [6 7]]]
```

I want to remove the elements in the same column, e.g. column 1. So the result should be:

```
=[[[1]
   [3]]
  [[0]
   [6]]]
```

I tried the np.delete function:

```
print np.delete(array[:][:],1,axis=1)
```

But it dosen't produce the desired result, instead I get:

```
=[[[1 2]]
  [[0 5]]]
```

I found this in the np doc [(Link)](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html):

```
np.delete(array, np.s_[::2], 1)
```

But this seems to only remove the uneven Numbers and I don't know how to modify it. Also the doc on the [np.s](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.s_.html) Function did not take me any further.

Any Help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Since this is a 3d-array, you should delete `axis=2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your array is a *three* dimensional array, so in case you want to delete the items with index `1` of the last index, you should use:

```
np.delete(array[:][:], 1, axis=2)
```

Note that you do *not* need the `[:][:]` part: this will have no effect, so you can use:

```
np.delete(array, 1, axis=2)
```

This will then generate:

```
>>> np.delete(array, 1, axis=2)
array([[[1],
        [3]],

       [[0],
        [6]]])
```

Comment: How would I delete just one element from each 2D array?

Comment: @mLstudent33: A numpy array can only store "rectangular" data, so how would you remove one element from a 2d array?

Comment: Van Onsen, thanks, I made a copy to copy into by deleting the column index for a row in a for loop instead.

Answer (score 2):

Deleting using axis= [0, 1] works while your working with 2d arrays. As the dimension increases, accordingly the axis value should also be increased.
This should work.

```
np.delete(array[:][:], 1, axis=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can very well use basic slicing since [`np.delete()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html) doesn't actually *delete* anything from the original array. Instead it returns a copy (of what you're requesting).

```
In [242]: arr
Out[242]: 
array([[[1, 2],
        [3, 4]],

       [[0, 5],
        [6, 7]]])

# select both slices, select all rows but only first column
In [243]: arr[:, :, :1]
Out[243]: 
array([[[1],
        [3]],

       [[0],
        [6]]])

# same case as above but you can omit the `:`s with a single `...`
In [244]: arr[..., :1]
Out[244]: 
array([[[1],
        [3]],

       [[0],
        [6]]])

# sanity check for no copy made
In [245]: (arr[..., :1]).flags
Out[245]: 
  C_CONTIGUOUS : False
  F_CONTIGUOUS : False
  OWNDATA : False   # <=========== NO copy
  WRITEABLE : True
  ALIGNED : True
  UPDATEIFCOPY : False
```

---

However, as already mentioned, [`np.delete()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html) **returns the result as a copy**.

```
In [246]: np.delete(arr[:][:], 1, axis=2).flags
Out[246]: 
  C_CONTIGUOUS : True
  F_CONTIGUOUS : False
  OWNDATA : True    # <========= Its own copy
  WRITEABLE : True
  ALIGNED : True
  UPDATEIFCOPY : False
```

---

However, if you're slicing from original array, you've to be careful while you make any changes to the result so that you don't accidentally change the original array.